# JavaScript - Promise fulfilled too early?

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2

I created a small sample application using VueJs and created a C# REST API to store and retrieve data in a SQL Server back end.

For testing, I created a simple web page with a form to create a "note". The note is stored by the following function, 'saveData()':

```
    saveData()
    {
        let promiseStack = [];
        var jsondata = JSON.stringify(this.note);

        promiseStack.push(this.$http.post('REST_API/note', jsondata));

        Promise.all(promiseStack).then(data =>
        {
            this.$http.get('REST_API/note');
            this.$router.push({ name: 'viewnotes', params: { id: data[0].body.id }})
        }, error =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        });     
    }
```

I tried to use a promise to wait until the 'store' operation in the backend is complete, and issue a GET request to retrieve all notes once the promise is fulfilled.

However, the get request inside the promise doesn't return any data. If I issue the get request manually later one, I retrieve the data that was stored previously.

So I had look into the C# REST API. There are currently two functions: createNote(...), getAllNotes(...). I used a StreamWriter to log to the filesystem when these functions are called, using milisecond precision. What I see is that 'createNote' is called after 'getAllNotes'. So I suspect that the API is working correctly, but something with the way I'm using promises seems to be awfully wrong.

Maybe somebody has a hint?

UPDATE

- I know that the GET request doesn't return any data by using the developer toolbar in Chromium. The response is empty
- The developer toolbar in the network tab shows that the requests are submitted in the correct order, so the "POST" request is issued first

Comment: How do you know the GET request isn't returning any data?

Comment: What does your browser's network inspector say which order the requests are triggered in?

Comment: If the network tab shows requests in the right order, but system calls happen out of order, then the API sounds like the broken part.

Comment: You may need to use `return Promise.all` in `saveData`.

Comment: @ssube: No, not necessarily. The "create" request could be submitted, and just after that the 'get' request could be submitted, without giving the 'create' request time to complete.

Comment: @shawon191: Well, I thought that might be the case, but I'm quite unsure: Would I need to do something with that returned 'Promise.all'?

Comment: @inzanez You need to use `saveData().then(function() { /*statements that need to run after saving data*/})`

Comment: I just checked the webserver logs as well, the get request seems to be processed (and logged) before the POST request,...

Comment: @shawon191 No, the `then` appears to be the end of the chain. It's fine not to return a promise to the caller in that case. You only would `return` that promise if the caller of `saveData` is interested in waiting for the route to change or the error to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the problem. I had a 'href' tag in my 'Save' link, which triggered an early routing. The intended 'POST' and 'GET' were fired correctly, but there was another 'GET' inbetween somewhere because of the 'href' tag in the link, even though it was empty.

I removed the tag, now it works as intended.